How can add user attributes like (name, avatar) to respective users in video conference in Agora SDK in React
I am using agora-rtc-react and building a video conference app on top of it, I am confused on how to add user attributes, Agora docs doesn't provide specific answer to this. In my app users have to authenticate themselves in a lobby page where they will input their name and avatar, I tried to find a workaround with useRemoteUsers() hook provided by agora-rtc-react, useRemoteUsers() lists remote users and their uids but the uids change everytime users reconnect. Please help me approach this or what am i missing in this
import AgoraRTC, {
  LocalUser,
  LocalVideoTrack,
  RemoteUser,
  useJoin,
  useLocalCameraTrack,
  useLocalMicrophoneTrack,
  usePublish,
  useRemoteAudioTracks,
  useRemoteUsers,
  AgoraRTCScreenShareProvider,
  useRTCScreenShareClient,
  useLocalScreenTrack,
  AgoraRTCScreenShareProviderProps
} from "agora-rtc-react";

  // set the connection state
  const [activeConnection, setActiveConnection] = useState(true);

  // track the mic/video state - Turn on Mic and Camera On
  const [micOn, setMic] = useState(true);
  const [cameraOn, setCamera] = useState(true);

  // get local video and mic tracks
  const { localMicrophoneTrack } = useLocalMicrophoneTrack(micOn);
  const { localCameraTrack } = useLocalCameraTrack(cameraOn);


  // Join the channel
  useJoin(
    {
      appid: appId as string,
      channel: 'video-call'!,
      token: null,
    },
    activeConnection,
  );

  usePublish([localMicrophoneTrack, localCameraTrack]);

  //remote users
  const remoteUsers = useRemoteUsers();

  console.log("remote users", remoteUsers)

I thought an approach where I would fetch the uid assigned to each remoteUser and add it to users DB while creating the user in lobby page, and then in the video call page I'll fetch the users data and map it to the videos with their repective uids, but uids are changing i don't know why. Is there any flaw with my approach or does agora already provides solution for this...?

